# Link error with cblas when installing scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, atlas, cblas

On my RHEL7, I am trying to install [py-earth](https://github.com/jcrudy/py-earth)  and getting this link error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
```

I have packages blas, blas-devel, atlas and atlas-devel installed.

The compilation command printed after this error specifies

```
-L/usr/lib64/atlas -lcblas -lm ....
```

And for completeness, the directory `/usr/lib64/atlas` contains the following files and symlinks

```
libsatlas.so -> libsatlas.so.3.10
libsatlas.so.3 -> libsatlas.so.3.10
libsatlas.so.3.10
libtatlas.so -> libtatlas.so.3.10
libtatlas.so.3 -> libtatlas.so.3.10
libtatlas.so.3.10
```

Any help?

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a problem with sklearn, not understanding that the atlas package now comes as a shared .so file, instead of multiple ones. You can see the problem at this [github issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5489).

My solution was the last one offered: simply create a link:

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/atlas/libsatlas.so /usr/lib64/atlas/libcblas.so
```

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

As Ian Roddis noted, this is a bug in scikit-learn.

Another workaround on Linux is upgrading **pip** to a version **>=8.1**. Then pip can install the "many-linux" binary wheel instead of compiling scikit-learn from source. (The binary wheel does not have this issue)